# Alternative characterization of exterior algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Throughout literature, the exterior algebra $\Lambda(V)$ over an $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{K}$-vector space $V$ is introduced as being the quotient $T(V)/I$ of the tensor algebra $T(V)$ by the ideal $I$ generated by elements of the form $x \otimes x$.

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3350) presentation, instead, a subset $\mathcal{D}$ is defined comprising linear combinations of elements $v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k$ such that $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ are linearly dependent. It is stated that $\mathcal{D}$ is clearly an ideal, $\Lambda(V)$ is defined as the quotient $T(V)/\mathcal{D}$.

Are these two formulations equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $I = D$. We clearly have $I \subseteq D$ and the usual proof that exterior products of linearly dependent vectors vanish in the exterior algebra proves that $D \subseteq I$. This construction is just being more explicit about what the ideal generated by elements of the form $x \otimes x$ actually looks like.

Comment: I'm still confused how elements of $D$ can be put into the form of linear combinations of $x \otimes x$.

Comment: @user: are you familiar with the proof that exterior products of linearly dependent vectors vanish in the exterior algebra? Write that proof down, but every time you use the fact that $v \wedge v = 0$ to conclude that two elements $a, b$ in the exterior algebra are equal, instead write out explicitly what the difference $a - b$ is, in terms of $v \otimes v$.

Comment: As a simple example, suppose $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are linearly dependent, and that (after possibly reindexing if necessary) $v_1, _2$ are linearly independent. This means $v_3 = av_1 + bv_2$ for some $a, b$, so $v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes v_3 = v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes (av_1) + v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes (bv_2)$. The second term is $bv_1$ times $v_2 \otimes v_2$ so that's why it lies in $I$. The first term requires a bit more work; the way we'd prove that $v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge (av_1) = 0$ in the exterior algebra involves commuting $v_1$ and $v_2$, so we need to write...

Comment: ...$v_1 \otimes v_2 = v_2 \otimes v_1 + [v_1, v_2]$ (where $[v_1, v_2]$ denotes the commutator) and so $v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes (av_1) = av_2 \otimes (v_1 \otimes v_1) + [v_1 v_2] \otimes av_1$. The first term is $av_2$ times $(v_1 \otimes v_1)$ so that's why it lies in $I$. Now we need to know why $[v_1, v_2] \in I$. For this we reproduce the proof that alternating implies antisymmetric; explicitly, we have $(v_1 + v_2) \otimes (v_1 + v_2) \in I$ and $(v_1 - v_2) \otimes (v_1 - v_2) \in I$ and then we subtract them and divide by $2$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Whoops, that last bit's not quite right, we instead use $(v_1 + v_2) \otimes (v_1 + v_2) \in I$ and then $v_1 \otimes v_1 \in I, v_2 \otimes v_2 \in I$, and we need $[v_1, v_2]$ to be the anticommutator instead, which changes a few signs.